# ¿Cómo determinar si un array que recibe datos de una API REST se está cargando de cuando termina de cargarse? para usar esos datos en React

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

En una aplicación web con react estoy usando dos API Rest cuyos datos administro con createContex para poder pasarlos a cualquier componente, sin embargo en la primera carga devolvió 10 arrays vacíos y luego 10 llenas con los datos que necesitaba pero solo necesitaba un array, esto disminuyó mucho el rendimiento ya que hay muchas cargas innsesarias

La solución a la que llegué fue pasar el context a index.js para realizar la llamada hai a las api  rest al realizar la llamada en app.jsx  si el array estuviera vacío, devolvería un spiner, pero si estuviera lleno todo el app.
llamada a las api rest

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export const ViewContext = createContext();
const RestView = (props) => {
  const urlRestApi = "";
  const urlImage = "";

  const [arrRest, setArrRest] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function loadPosts() {
      try {
        axios.get(`${urlRestApi}`)
          .then((post) => {
            const posts = post.data.map((data) => ({
              titulo: data.title.rendered,
              contenido: data.content.rendered, 
              extracto: data.excerpt.rendered,
              idImagen: data.featured_media,
            }));
            const imagePostPromises = posts.map((post) => {
              return axios.get(`${urlImage}/${post.idImagen}`) 
                .then((imageData) => ({
                  ...post,
                  imagenes: imageData.data.source_url, 
                }));
            });
            return axios.all(imagePostPromises);
          })
          .then((postsWithImages) => {
            console.log(postsWithImages); 
            setArrRest(postsWithImages);
          });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    loadPosts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ViewContext.Provider
      value={{
        arrRest,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ViewContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RestView;
```

en app.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import "fontsource-roboto";
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import Slide from 'react-reveal/Slide';
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Featured from "./components/Featured";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import BlogOne from "./pages/BlogOne";
import BlogTwo from "./pages/BlogTwo";
import BlogThree from "./pages/BlogThree";
import PageError from "./pages/PageError";
import "./App.css";
import { ViewContext } from "./components/Context/ContexPost";
function App() {
  const { arrRest } = useContext(ViewContext);
  console.log("EN APP", arrRest);

  if(arrRest.length === 0)
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sk-fading-circle">
          <div className="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
          <div className="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  
   
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Fade left>
        <NavBar />
        </Fade>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Blog} />
            <Route exact path="/blog1" component={BlogOne} />
            <Route exact path="/blog2" component={BlogTwo} />
            <Route exact path="/blog3" component={BlogThree} />
            <Route component={PageError} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <Slide right>
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <main>
            <Featured />
          </main>
        </Container>
        </Slide>
        <Slide right>
        <Footer />
        </Slide>
      </Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Pero mis superiores me dicen que es el enfoque correcto pero no la forma correcta, que no debería usar if (array.length === 0) porque lo que tengo que hacer es comprobar si está cargando los elementos y cuando  Termine de cargar, eso con lo que hice desde cuando no hay elementos hasta cuando hay que son cosas diferentes

¿Cómo puedo verificar cuándo se está cargando el array y cuándo ha terminado de cargarse?

No, mis superiores no me van a decir cómo hacerlo es como una especie de prueba, por si acaso

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo con un customHook que te puede servir: https://github.com/john-smilga/react-advanced-2020/blob/master/src/tutorial/9-custom-hooks/final/2-useFetch.js